# On page refresh, how does the session storage work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to show a dialog on clicking add button. and not display it for the session (using sessionstorage) when hide button is clicked.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    const DialogRequest = useDialogRequest();
    const onAdd = () => {
        DialogRequest(true);
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <button onClick={onAdd}>Add</button>
        );
    }
}
```

function Dialog(onHide) {
        return(
            {showDialog? 
                hide : null
            }
        );
    }

```
const dialogRequestContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({});

export const DialogRequestProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [showDialog,setShowDialog] = React.useState(false);

    const onHide = () => {
        setDialogOpen(false);
    };
    const setDialogOpen = (open: boolean) => {
        if (open) {
            const sessionDialogClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('dialog');
            if (sessionDialogClosed !== 'closed') {
                setShowDialog(open);
                sessionStorage.setItem('dialog', 'closed');
            }
        } else {
            setShowDialog(open);
        }
    };
    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider
            value={{ setDialogOpen }}
        >
            {children}
            <Dialog onHide={onHide}
                showDialog={showDialog}
            />
        </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
};



export function useDialogRequest() {
    const dialogRequestContext = React.useContext(
        dialogRequestContext
    );


    return function DialogRequest(open: boolean) {
        if (dialogRequestContext &&
            dialogRequestContext.setDialogOpen
        ) {
            dialogRequestContext.setDialogOpen(open);
          }
    };
}
```

This code works.but when page reloads then the dialog is not opened again even though hide message is not clicked before page reload.

i have tried to console log the value of dialog like below after page reload.

```
if (open) {
    const sessionDialogClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('dialog');
    console.log('sessiondialogclosed', sessionDialogClosed); //this gives closed 
    if (sessionDialogClosed !== 'closed') {
        setShowDialog(open);
        sessionStorage.setItem('dialog', 'closed');
    }
} else {
    setShowDialog(open);
}
```

Even though i dint click the hide button before page reload.....this gives me the ouput closed for the sessionstorage item dialog.

Not sure if this is the way it should behave. If not could someone help me fix this to get it right.

thanks.

Comment: Values in `useState` persist for the life of the page. They won't be kept across a page refresh. If you need to do that, you might consider creating a hook that wraps `useState` which persists the values into `localStorage`, and then retrieves the initial value on page load?

Comment: could you provide an example to do this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expressed in my comment:

> Values in useState persist for the life of the page. They won't be kept across a page refresh. If you need to do that, you might consider creating a hook that wraps useState which persists the values into localStorage, and then retrieves the initial value on page load.

This is a basic example of such a hook.

```
function usePersistentState(defaultValue, key) {
  let initVal;
  try {
    initVal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  } catch {}
  if (initVal === undefined) initVal = defaultValue;

  const [state, setState] = useState(initVal);
  function persistState(value) {
    if (typeof value === "function") value = value(state);
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    setState(value);
  }
  return [state, persistState];
}
```

Here's a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-3o10n?file=/src/index.js) of how it works. If you refresh the page after toggling the value, it will restore the previous state from `localStorage`.

There are a few caveats about how it works. If you've got a really complex state you shouldn't use this, you should do basically the same thing but with [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead. But in a simple example like this should be fine.